# How do I convert date formats using a regex in R?

Tags: r, date, stringr

I need to convert dates in my dataframe, from "mddyy" to "m_dd_yyyy" (or "m_d_yyyy") format.

Current data looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("81617", "80117", "62817"))
df
      x
1 81617
2 80117
3 62817
```

Desired output:

```
df
          x
1 8_16_2017
2  8_1_2017
3 6_28_2017
```

Perhaps removing zero values for days between 1-9 using str_remove(), then apply a regex to insert underscores and the "20" prefix to year would work?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you want to convert to dates, why not convert to `Date`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sub`

```
sub("(\\d+)(\\d{2})(\\d{2})$", "\\1_\\2_20\\3", df$x)
```

Removing leading 0

```
gsub("_0", "_", sub("(\\d+)(\\d{2})(\\d{2})$", "\\1_\\2_20\\3", df$x))

[1] "8_16_2017" "8_1_2017"  "6_28_2017"
```

Answer (score 2):

No regex required.

This (updated) answer goes to @Henrik:

```r
as.Date(sprintf("%06d", as.integer(vec)), format = "%m%d%y")
# [1] "2017-08-16" "2017-08-01" "2017-06-28"
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @r2evans mentioned, you might be better off converting to a true date object, then utilizing `Date`'s format method. This is safer than regex or string pasting to deal with situations such as having dates from different centuries.

To get a date, you'll want to pad the month portion with a 0. I'm doing that with `stringr::str_pad` because it's easy, and added a date that *doesn't* need padding in order to have another test case.

```r
x <- c("81617", "80117", "62817", "120816")
dates <- as.Date(stringr::str_pad(x, width = 6, side = "left", pad = "0"), 
                 format = "%m%d%y")
strftime(dates, format = "%m_%d_%Y")
#> [1] "08_16_2017" "08_01_2017" "06_28_2017" "12_08_2016"
```

In your example, you show them without the 0 padding in the months or dates. Using regex, you can remove any 0s that follow either the beginning of the string or a `_`.

```r
gsub("(?<=^|_)0", "", strftime(dates, format = "%m_%d_%Y"), perl = TRUE)
#> [1] "8_16_2017" "8_1_2017"  "6_28_2017" "12_8_2016"
```